# is it safe to remove the /tmp/hive/hive folder?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, ambari

is it safe to remove the **/tmp/hive/hive** folder? ( from hdfs )

as ( from user hdfs )

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r /tmp/hive/hive
```

the reason for that because under /tmp/hive/hive we have thousand of files and we cant delete them

```
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/hive/
Found 7 items
drwx------   - admin     hdfs          0 2019-03-05 12:00 /tmp/hive/admin
drwx------   - drt       hdfs          0 2019-06-16 14:02 /tmp/hive/drt
drwx------   - ambari-qa hdfs          0 2019-06-16 15:11 /tmp/hive/ambari-qa
drwx------   - anonymous hdfs          0 2019-06-16 08:57 /tmp/hive/anonymous
drwx------   - hdfs      hdfs          0 2019-06-13 08:42 /tmp/hive/hdfs
drwx------   - hive      hdfs          0 2019-06-13 10:58 /tmp/hive/hive
drwx------   - root      hdfs          0 2018-07-17 23:37 /tmp/hive/root
```

what we did until now - as the following is to remove the files that are older then 10 days ,

but because there are so many files then files not deleted at all

```
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/hive/hive   |   tr -s " "    |    cut -d' ' -f6-8    |     grep "^[0-9]"    |    awk 'BEGIN{ MIN=14400; LAST=60*MIN; "date +%s" | getline NOW } { cmd="date -d'\''"$1" "$2"'\'' +%s"; cmd | getline WHEN; DIFF=NOW-WHEN; if(DIFF > LAST){ print "Deleting: "$3; system("hdfs dfs -rm -r "$3) }}'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HiveServer2 generate a lot of directories in hdfs /tmp/hive/hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306404/hiveserver2-generate-a-lot-of-directories-in-hdfs-tmp-hive-hive) also Look at https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/55496/safe-to-delete-under-tmp-in-hdfs-how-about-tmphive.html might be helpful.